# C++ Json library building

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I use https://github.com/nlohmann/json to handle in C++, I tried to build a simple code :

```
#include "lib/json-lib/json.hpp"
using json = nlohmann::json;

int main() {
   json jsonConfiguration;
    while(1){
        std::cout << "Hello Wolrd!" <<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I take the file `json.hpp` from https://github.com/nlohmann/json/tree/develop/single_include/nlohmann
i saved this one under `lib/json-lib`. I build my main.cpp with `g++ main.cpp` and when i launch it after build i got this :

[image: bug screenshoot]

Comment: I can only guess what the error message says because it is not in english, but my guess is that you don’t link against the `stdlib` and as of that `std::basic_string` is not known.

Comment: indeed i'm sorry i forgot to give traduction but i find a solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use MinGW to build my file.

As you can read here :

> If you use MinGW, then copy libstdc++-6.dll and libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
>   into the same folder as your executable. – salted Sep 2 '17 at 22:44

So i did it and that works well, these files are stored in "/bin"